# How it was recorded 'One After 909' (The Beatles)

Tags: the-beatles

Could someone tell me how it was recorded 'One After 909' (The Beatles)
where it was recorded? in the studio or on the roof?

Answer (score 3):

[one after 909 - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_After_909)

> ...originally released in 1970 on the album Let It Be. The album version is the live performance from the rooftop concert which took place on 30 January 1969. This performance is also included in the Let It Be film
>
> On 5 March 1963, the Beatles recorded a version of the song in 5 takes during the same session that produced their third single, "From Me to You", and its B-side "Thank You Girl". They were unhappy with the result and that version was not released at the time.[6] Various takes from the 5 March session, and an edit of them, were released in 1995 on the Anthology 1 compilation.
>
> "One After 909" is included on 2003's Let It Be... Naked, in a remixed and remastered version of the 1969 rooftop concert take